# how does the inside of aside header(impacts on markets) displayed in sienna color?

Tags: html, css

I am currently preparing for 70-480 Microsoft exam. The below code is  HTML5 page that displays a news article. The CSS markup for the page is as follows:

```css
<style>
h4
{
    color:powderblue;
}
.headline
{
    color:red;
}
article
{
    color:black;
    font-style:normal;
}
aside h4
{
    font-style:italic !important;
    color:yellow;
}
article h4
{
    color:sienna;
    font-style:normal;
}
</style>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <h4>International News</h4>
            <article>
                <h4 class="headline">New Developments!</h4>
                <aside>
                    <h4>Impacts On Markets</h4>
                </aside>
            </article>
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

How does the inside of aside `<h4>` tag that is "Impacts On Markets" display in sienna color?

Answer (score 0):

Because of this style:

```
article h4
{
    color:sienna;
    font-style:normal;
}
```

is *below* this style:

```
aside h4
{
    font-style:italic !important;
    color:yellow;
}
```

Because CSS is **cascading**, the lowest applicable style is applied. In this case, your "Impacts on Markets" `<h4>` still matches the `article h4` style and since this occurs last, the `color:sienna' is applied.